# How do I zip multiple arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, zip

How do I zip 3 or more arrays in ruby?

```
A = ['a','b']
B = ['c','d']
C = ['e','f']
```

`A.zip(B).zip(C)` is not optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier than expected...

```
A.zip(B,C)
```